# Ansible win_package & win_shell - How to pass arguments that have quotes to a command?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

How to pass these arguments that have several double quotes correctly?

```
  tasks:
  - name: Install McAfee tp
    win_shell: |
      D:\vra_install\AV\setupEP.exe ADDLOCAL="tp" INSTALLDIR="D:\Program Files" /qb /l"D:\temp\"
    args:
      executable: cmd

[root]# ansible-playbook  mcafee-win-install.yml -e "host=prx103"
ERROR! failed at splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2 block or quotes: D:\vra_install\AV\setupEP.exe ADDLOCAL="tp" INSTALLDIR="D:\Program Files" /qb /l"D:\temp\"
```

I tried win_package implementation but the program does not want to install. I guess the arguments were not passed correctly.

```
  - name: Install TP
    win_package:
      path: D:\vra_install\AV\setupEP.exe
      arguments:
      - ADDLOCAL="tp" 
      - INSTALLDIR="D:\Program Files" 
      - /qb 
      - /l"D:\temp\" '
      creates_path: D:\Program Files\McAfee\Endpoint Security\Threat Prevention\AMCore
      creates_service: mfevtp
      state: present

fatal: [veaprdprx103]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "unexpected rc from install  D:\\vra_install\\AV\\setupEP.exe: see rc, stdout and stderr for more details",
    "rc": 16019,
    "reboot_required": false,
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
```

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is most likely `/l"D:\temp\"`: the `\"` at the end is interpreted as an _escaped `"`_ rather than a literal ``\`` followed by a `"`; try `/l"D:\temp\\"` - or, if the trailing ``\`` isn't actually needed, `/l"D:\temp"`

Answer (score 0):

I would try using single quotes for the full string.

E.G.:

```yaml
  tasks:
  - name: Install McAfee tp.
    win_shell: |
      'D:\vra_install\AV\setupEP.exe ADDLOCAL="tp" INSTALLDIR="D:\Program Files" /qb /l"D:\temp\"'
    args:
      executable: cmd
```